# Apache Artemis: create instance accessible from any address

Tags: cors, activemq-artemis

I downloaded Apache Artemis 2.16.0 from the official site and created an instance with command `artemis create --http-host 0.0.0.0 --user default --password --default -- /var/lib/artemis`.

I set `http-host` to `0.0.0.0`, to let me access the management console from any address. This lets me access the console, but the configuration is wrong, since it sets the `jolokia-access.xml:restrict.cors.allow-origin` to `*://0.0.0.0*`, which means that even though I can technically access the console, I get no data, just a mostly empty screen.

I can, by hand, edit the file attribute to `*://*`, but I'd prefer having the command do this to me instead. Is it a bug in the instance generator, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created [this Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3062) initially, but after additional consideration I've chosen to leave the behavior as-is.

Using `0.0.0.0` for the `http-host` is convenient in one sense because it allows the embedded HTTP server to listen for connections on *every* network interface. However, the embedded HTTP server has no knowledge of what *actual* IP addresses or hostnames will be used by browser clients. Therefore, instead of the broker automatically configuring `*://*` for CORS and allowing *any* cross-site access (which is not recommended from a security perspective) it will be up to the user to configure this since only the user knows the real, proper values.